# How is a Mobile OS different from a desktop OS

Tags: operating-system

I'm talking about a modern mobile OS such as Android/iOS versus modern desktop OSes such Linux/Windows.

I understand that they're a lot more lightweight. I'm wondering what exact low level features are missing or are different.

Comment: For starters, they don't have to support the same variety of hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gaps between the two are getting smaller and smaller - witness the introduction of multicore processors to the mobile environment with phones such as the Galaxy S II.
By having such "high"-powered hardware available, it is necessary for the OS to provide features once considered the domain of supercomputers, such as parallel processing and synchronization.

In theory, Android being a Linux distribution should be able to scale up to the full feature set of the desktop computer. As for not having to support the same variety of hardware, that is definitely open to contention - consider the device fragmentation (and OS fragmentation for that matter) that makes it so difficult to write apps for Android that will function on many phones. If you want to write an app that is accessible across many device architectures this requires targetting a much older release of Android than the latest version available on newer phones.

From an operating systems perspective this is much reduced on the iOS architecture where Apple applies a consistent upgrade policy and the devices themselves are guarranteed to have certain hardware configurations - something that cannot be said for Android.

The way OS development for phones is going (towards bridging the gap between mobile and desktop), the differences between the OSs become less significant.

Of course, the major difference would be the processor that is targetted. Linux/Windows work find on x86 and 64, but Android functions soley on ARM (although there is a project to port it to x86).